# SQL Match group of records to another group of records

Tags: sql

Is there SQL statement to match up multiple records to an exact match of multiple records in another table?

Lets say I have table A

```
ID | List# | Item
1  |   5   |  A
2  |   5   |  C
3  |   5   |  B
4  |   6   |  A
5  |   6   |  D
```

*I purposely made Items 'ABC' out of order as the order of the records I receive may be out of order.

```
Table B
ID |  Group  | Item
1  |   AAA   |  A
2  |   AAA   |  B
3  |   AAA   |  C
4  |   AAA   |  D
5  |   BBB   |  A
6  |   BBB   |  B
7  |   BBB   |  C
8  |   DDD   |  A
```

If looking at the first table, I would want List# 5 to return a match only for group 'BBB', as all (and only) three records match.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: SQL does not natively implement table division. It can be simulated, however.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to aggregate into a string or array and `join`.  Standard SQL supports `listagg()`, so you can do:

```
select a.list, b.list, a.items
from (select a.list, listagg(item, ',') within group (order by item) as items
      from a
      group by a.list
     ) a join
     (select b.list, listagg(item, ',') within group (order by item) as items
      from b
      group by b.list
     ) b 
     on a.items = b.items;
```

Not all databases support `listagg()`.  Many -- but not all -- have similar functionality.  This is simpler than the "standard" SQL approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate database division. It's a little bit cumbersome but here it is:

```
with
x as (
  select 
  from a
  where a.list = 5
),
y as (
  select grp, count(*) as cnt
  from b
  join x on x.item = b.item
  group by grp
)
select grp
from y
where cnt = (select count(*) from x)
```